# Camel IBM MQ reconnection strategy

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-mq

We are facing an issue when the application is idle for sometime and when we try to send a message to IBM MQ we receive a a 2009 MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN.Does camel have a reconnection strategy to check and reconnect to IBM MQ again.How do we configure this or should the application need to catch this, do a clean-up of the app state, and re-establish the connection.

Comment: Are you using jms or your own client via the MQ jars?

Comment: own client via MQ jars

Comment: What version of the IBM MQ jar files are you using, on Linux you can do something like the this on any of the com.ibm.mq jar files: `unzip -p com.ibm.mq.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep Specification-Version`.

Comment: What is the HBINT set to on the SvRCONN channel defined on the queue manager?  What does the AMQERR01.LOG indicate when you come across this error?

Comment: IBM MQ Version 7.1.0.6

Comment: HBInt -300 secs ( Default Value)

Comment: What is SHARECNV set to on the SVRCONN, and what is the TCP KEEPALIVE set to on the server where the queue manager is running?

Comment: SHARECNV is set to 1 .THis is a remote MQ, how can i check the KAINT value .Can i do it through MQ explorer

Comment: The TCP KEEPALIVE would be a OS level setting, for instance on Linux you would run "sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time" to view the setting.  It would also be good to know what this is on your client side as well.  Note that I'm a MQ admin and do not know a lot about Camel, but was hoping to help you address the underlying cause of the connection getting a 2009 when it is idle for some time.